# Loop through attributes in XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to loop through attributes in my xml with simplexml, but it does not work quite well.

When I'm viewing the output in my browser, only one row is outputted. When I'm trying to run the script via command line, I get this error message:

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/test/index.php on line 11

Here is my php code :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    foreach($xml->packet->proto[$i] as $a)
    {
        if($a->attributes() == "http.request.full_uri" || $a->attributes() == "ip.src")
        {
            echo $a->attributes() . ": " . $a->attributes()->showname . "<br>" ;
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

Anyone who can help me to get all the attributes that have the names as specified in my if clause?

Comment: You have to provide content of `test.xml`

Comment: My guess is that there aren't 1000 `$xml->packet->proto` elements. Why not try `print_r()`ing each one in the loop? That way you can see how many iterations your outer loop reaches before the error occurs.

Comment: `print_r($xml->packet->proto);` contains your answer

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky the value of print_r is this: http://pastebin.com/d43VB2aY

Am I doing correct with the foreach, or how should it be?

Comment: @Jeff the value of print_r is this: pastebin.com/d43VB2aY Am I doing correct with the foreach, or how should it be?

Comment: I'm replying in a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies here:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
```

Why are you checking 1000 `$xml->packet->proto` entries? It looks like there aren't that many. You should use `foreach` there as well - something like this:

```
foreach($xml->packet->proto as $proto) {
    foreach($proto as $a) {
        // ...
```

I'm sort of guessing how your XML is structured, but hopefully this helps point you in the right direction. The error message `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` is sort of telling you the problem. It's because you're trying to access `$xml->packet->proto[$i]` where `$i` is an index that is out of bounds, causing an error.

Comment: Sorry, but that don't work. Now nothing is echoed out.

Comment: The problem with your code is that it only loops through gets ONE packet-section, instead of ALL the packet sections in the XML. That's why Im tried to use a for loop in some kind. But it seems like I solved the issue with xpath.

Comment: @user500468 come on, edit your question and provide that XML!